# how to change the colour of this background

Tags: css

hello friends i am new here so i want to know how to change the of color in css for this site - https://filmyworld.wiki/download-pastor-thorne-lust-of-the-flesh-2022-full-movie-720p/
[image]

i have marked with the arrow

Answer (score 1):

It's an inline style. Just change the preferred color from the following tag:

```
<p class="has-text-align-center has-black-color has-text-color has-background has-medium-font-size" style="background-color:#(Preferred color)">...</p>
```